# accessing properties of a property from a method in a property of a class in coffeescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I want to be able to access a property of a `class` property from a method of a `class` property.

```
// lets say
class foo
  constructor: () ->
  vars: {
    bar: "somevalue"
  },
  op: {
    baz: () ->
      #get the value of foo.vars.bar
  }
```

How do I do it, it returns undefined if i try `foo.vars.bar`

**EDIT**

Sorry for not making it so clear, I want

```
baz: () ->
  something = foo.vars.bar
```

Is there a simple way to do it, because

```
baz: () ->
   something = foo.prototype.vars.bar
```

works fine.

Comment: Works for me... Make sure you instantiate the object first. Adding `x = new foo; console.log x.vars.bar` results in: `=> "somevalue"`. Fiddle included: http://jsfiddle.net/XL9aH/

Comment: see edit, sorry for not making it clear

Comment: Added an answer with a way to access the class instance from within these nested methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two ways you can do this:  always access `foo.vars` via the foo prototype (as you've discovered) like this:

```
foo::vars.bar
```

(`foo::` is a shortcut for `foo.prototype` in coffeescript)

Or you could ensure that the context of `bar` is bound to an instance of `foo` when it's called.  One way to do this would be to bind it in the `foo` constructor:

```
class foo
  constructor: () ->
    @op.baz = @op.baz.bind @
  vars: {
    bar: "somevalue"
  },
  op: {
    baz: () ->
      console.log @vars.bar
  }
```

Which of these is most suitable probably depends on whether you want to use the same `vars` object across all classes or not.  The second option probably isn't suitable if you want the context of `baz` to be something other than a `foo` instance.

Answer (score 2):

One potential way is to have the parent instance variable defined in the scope:

```
class foo
  this_foo = null # So that the var is available everywhere within this context block
  constructor: () ->
    this_foo = @
  vars: {
    bar: "somevalue"
  },
  op: {
    baz: () ->
      this_foo.vars.bar
  }
console.log (new foo).op.baz() # => somevalue
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XL9aH/3/

This solution will allow this instance of foo, `this_foo` (rename to your liking) to be accessed in other ops as well without binding them or changing their value for `this` (or coffee-script `@`).